# Assign values to dynamic arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, dynamic

My bash script needs to read values from a properties file and assign them to a number of arrays. The number of arrays is controlled via configuration as well. My current code is as follows:

```
limit=$(sed '/^\#/d' $propertiesFile | grep 'limit'  | tail -n 1 | cut -d "=" -f2- | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//')
for (( i = 1 ; i <= $limit ; i++ ))
do
   #properties that define values to be assigned to the arrays are labeled myprop## (e.g. myprop01, myprop02):
   lookupProperty=myprop$(printf "%.2d" "$i")
   #the following line reads the value of the lookupProperty, which is a set of space-delimited strings, and assigns it to the myArray# (myArray1, myArray2, etc):
   myArray$i=($(sed '/^\#/d' $propertiesFile | grep $lookupProperty  | tail -n 1 | cut -d "=" -f2- | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//'))
done
```

When I attempt to execute the above code, the following error message is displayed:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `$(sed '/^\#/d' $propertiesFile | grep $lookupProperty  | tail -n 1 | cut -d "=" -f2- | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//')'
```

I am quite sure the issue is in the way I am declaring the "myArray$i" arrays. However, any different approach I tried produced either the same errors or incomplete results.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that bash does not recognize the construct `myArray$i=(some array values)` as an array variable assignment.  One work-around is:

```
read -a myArray$i <<<"a b c"
```

The `read -a varname` command reads an array from stdin, which is provided by the "here" string `<<<"a b c",`  and assigns it to varname where varname can be constructs like myArray$i.  So, in your case, the command might look like:

```
read -a myArray$i <<<"$(sed '/^\#/d' $propertiesFile | grep$lookupProperty  | tail -n 1 | cut -d "=" -f2- | seds/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//')"
```

The above allows assignment.  The next issue is how to read out variables like myArray$i.  One solution is to name the variable indirectly like this:

```
var="myArray$i[2]" ; echo ${!var}
```